# How to use Singularity and Breakpoints without Ruby Sass on Drupal?

Tags: breakpoints, drupal-theming, singularitygs

I am falling out with my Drupal theme because of the terribly slow compilation times with Ruby Sass and Compass.

Recently I have tried a couple of alternative themes which are using Node and Gulp in conjunction with Bourbon and Neat. And to be honest I am blown away by the speed of these tools and the general improvement to my workflow.

That said, I am missing the versatility of the Singularity/Breakpoints combination and would like to know how to incorporate this with a node/gulp set up? Is this even possible?

Comment: I don't have a 100% answer for you but I just want to say that you basically have to test a bunch of theme setups and perhaps change the way you organize your folders/files/etc. Not really an optimal way to go, but I have chosen to go that way for now.

I am currently using gulp-compass with Drupal themes and use Singularity and Breakpoints everyday. I have recently started separating my theme into tons of partials and then compiling into 7-8 stylesheets.

Using gulp-compass new task: "watch" option, I am getting almost instant compiles and browser reloads.

Comment: That's interesting and I guess does answer some of my question regarding Singularity. Thank you